# use a string variable returned by a method in java

Tags: java, methods

Creating a text based game. I have a method for each of the following: Race, profession, name.
So for instance:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    intro();
    name();
    System.out.println("Welcome " + name);
}
public static String name(){
    System.out.println("Enter Name:");
    String name = sc.next();
    return name;
}
```

Yet I get an error when using the name variable in my print in main. Why?

Comment: What is `name` in `System.out.println("Welcome " + name);`? Read up on variable scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to assign the return value of `name` to a local variable:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    intro();
    String name = name();
    System.out.println("Welcome " + name);
}
public static String name(){
    System.out.println("Enter Name:");
    String name = sc.next();
    return name;
}
```

Comment: Or `System.out.println("Welcome " + name());`

Comment: @codeNinja It would help for the OP to learn variable assignments. One is not going to nest function calls in arguments for an entire program.

Comment: It's just another option. But right, you still shouldn't because it is good to have a variable to modify later on.

Answer (score 1):

Your `name()` method is static, but that doesn't necessarily mean that the `name`variable in that method can be accessed without a `getter` or something similar. It won't recognize that variable since it's only defined in that method.

You can try something like `Sysout("welcome" + name());` since your method will return that value.